# iPhone Email UI

Tags: iphone, ios, email, interface, uikit

We are building an iPhone application that will allow sending email like messages through our own backend server.  Ideally, we would like to have our UI to be very similar to the standard iOS Mail (ie. MFMailComposeViewController) but with some UI customization.

Does anyone know of a third-party control that we can use for our purpose? We are hoping to save time by building our custom control on existing work.

Answer (score 0):

The Three20 framework has [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) that seems to fit your needs.